# AWS KCL and handling errors

Tags: node.js, amazon-kcl, amazon-kinesis

The case. KCL reads a batch of 500 records from kinesis. Something bad happens (e.g. Unexpected error). KCL will lose all 500 records with data. Because KCL marks these 500 records as read and handled even though errors occur.

If I use AWS Lambdas instead of KCL, all records will be just read second time from kinesis after errors firing.

Can KCL behave like Lambdas and repeatedly read the same records from Kinesis if I got error before?

Comment: How are you planning to trigger Lambda? Kinesis Video Streams can't be used as trigger directly.

Comment: @py_ml I didn’t work with Kinesis Video Streams. But use a lot of regular Kinesis Streams. It’s possible to add triggers for lambdas in lambda’s configs. Kinesis is available as a trigger there.

Comment: Oh, sorry, somehow I managed to read Kinesis Video Stream, yes Kinesis Data Streams are available as trigger.